# How to eliminate duplicate in a dropdown, so I can calculate average cost of selected item in react - rails app?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, duplicates, dropdown, average

I created a dropdown with information from my seeds.rb (procedure and its cost), however, it is bringing duplicates as many users had the same procedure but with different cost. I would like the dropdown not to have duplicate but being able to calculate the average cost for the procedure chosen in the dropdown.

For example: 3 users indicated they did an x-ray and paid x, y, z for it. How can I make the dropdown to show x-ray only once, but capturing each of the costs so I can display an average cost for the x-ray (based on the amount of users who posted about it)?

I am using useState / useEffect to bring the info from rails and render in react. In react, I'm mapping and it to a  for the dropdown.

This is what I have:

```js
import Post from './Post';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

function Average ({posts, setUser, user}){
  
  const [procedures, setProcedures] = useState ([])
  const [filteredProcedure, setFilteredProcedure] = useState ("")

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/posts/${procedures}`)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then(setProcedures);
  }, []);

    //  get the filtered procedure array

    function handleProcedureChange(procedure) {
      setFilteredProcedure(procedure);
      console.log(procedure)
    }

    function handleFindProcedure () { 
      let url = `/posts/${procedures}`
      if (posts.filteredProcedure ) {
        url += `procedure=${posts.filteredProcedure}`;
      }
      fetch(url)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((procedureArray) => {
        setFilteredProcedure(procedureArray);
      });
    }

    function handleChange(e) {
      handleProcedureChange(e.target.value);
      console.log(e.target.value)
    }
  

  return (

    <div >


      <div >
      <label htmlFor="procedure">Procedure:</label>
      <select
        id="procedure"
        name="procedure"
        value={filteredProcedure}
        onChange={handleChange}      >
        <option value="">Select Procedure</option>
        {procedures.map((procedure) => (
          <option key={procedure.id} value={procedure.name}>
            {procedure.procedure} 
           {procedure.patient_cost}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
          </div>
          <div>
          {/* {procedures.map(procedure => {
            return (
              <li key={procedure.id}>
                {procedure.patient_cost}
              </li>
            )
          })} */}

          </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Average;
```

With that, I have the following dropdown:

[image]

Checking other questions/answers here, I tried using useMemo but I am not familiar with that and did not work.

My main goals are:

1. Dropdown with no duplicate.
2. Calculate average based on user's
   selection from the dropdown.

Please let me know if more information from my end is needed.

Comment: Write an aggregate query in rails controller that gets the average per procedure and return the results of that to your front end.

Comment: do you mean something like this? 
"class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    posts = Post.all 
    average = 0
    i = 0
    posts.each do |post|
      i += 1
      average += post.patient_cost
    end
    average = average / i
  end"

I am not sure how to test it.

Comment: tks, @dbugger. with the code above in rails, I was able to get the average cost from all posts. Each post indicates a procedure and its costs (among other things). I do not know how to get to all costs of a specific procedure. I tried adjusting the code to: "average += post.procedure.patient_cost", but it does not work.

Comment: Thats not a very effective way. Use something like `MyModel.select(Arel.star, MyModel.arel_table[:patient_cost].avg.as("average_patient_cost")).group(:some_column)` and let the database do the work. Databases are extremly effective at aggregation. Cobled together Ruby is not.

Comment: tks, @max. This is new to me. I started researching based on what you mentioned, and found someone indicating to add gem "scenic", and create view in Postgres. I ended up following the instruction thinking that it would kinda connect to what you mentioned above. I am still a bit lost on how it all work. So now I have a file "average_patient_cots_v01sql" with the following code:

Comment: SELECT
  posts.procedure AS procedure,
  posts.patient_cost AS procedure_cost,
  posts.id AS post_id,
  avg(posts.patient_cost) AS procedure_average
FROM posts
  INNER JOIN facilities ON (posts.facility_id = facilities.id)
  INNER JOIN users ON (posts.user_id = users.id)
GROUP BY facilities.id, posts.id,  users.id, posts.procedure, posts.patient_cost
I tried testing it in the console, but without success. Am I going to the right path, or completely off?  If the above is somehow correct, I do not know how to access the patient_cost that is one of the fields of a "post".

Comment: Using a database view is probally somewhat overkill for your requirements and something you might only need later (or not at all). Its not possible really for me or anyone else to help you with just a chunk of SQL dumped in a comment. Instead update your question with an example of your schema and models and what you want to get as an expected result. Possibly this has to be broken into several questions - I get that this is frustrating but you have to solve the backend concern first to even get to the JS part.

Comment: thanks, @max. I ll do more research and breakdown my question. Appreciate the support.